# The Question About Euler-Phi Function In Elementary Number Theory.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question in elementary number theory.

The Problem is :

Prove that there is no solution to the equation $f(n)=14$ (Now, $f$ is the Euler-Phi Function), and that $14$ is the smallest (positive) even integer with this property.

I know there is no solution to the equation $f(n)=14$, but "The Smallest Even Integer" is the problem. I don't know how to prove it.
If you solve this problem, I'll appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to just computing the values, you can also use the fact that if $n = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_s^{k_s}$, one has
$$
\varphi(n) = p_1^{k_1-1}(p_1-1)p_2^{k_2-1}(p_2-1)\ldots p_s^{k_s-1}(p_s-1)
$$
So if $\varphi(n) = 14 = 2\cdot 7$, it follows that $s=2$, and $k_i\leq 2$ for all $i$. Now
$$
p_1^{k_1-1}(p_1-1)p_2^{k_2-1}(p_2-1) = 14
$$
One can consider the cases $k_i \in \{1,2\}$ and prove that none of them are possible.